# Keeping full commit history local, remote merge to have a single commit

Tags: git

I would like to keep the whole development history of the branch locally ( multiple commits) 
But, for the remote merged branch to have a single commit only.
I was thinking of duplicating the branch, squashing it and then pushing it with --force to the remote development branch, and then merging. is there a faster way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can :

- locally: store your current branch with another name, e.g : `history/development`
- locally: create a new `development` branch with one single commit containing your current code
- locally: run `git replace development history/development`
- on the remote: run `push -force-with-lease development` to replace the remote development branch with the 1 commit version
- (if you want everyone to have access to the old development branch)
  on the remote: push `history/development`, as a branch (everyone will fetch it automatically), or as a ref which is neither a branch nor a tag :
  `git push origin history/development:refs/history/development`
  users will be able to view this ref by running `git ls-remote` and fetch it explicitly

---

The `git replace` command will make all local calls to `git log`, `git merge` or `git rebase` work as though you had one single `history` branch, while having a branch which stops at that initial commit -- for example : pushing and fetching will "stop" at that initial commit.

Comment: Thanks!  Do I simply merge  branch history to branch dev to create that single commit?

Comment: One way to create that single commit is : starting from your current dev branch, run `git reset --soft <sha of first commit in history>; git commit --amend`